# Please explain Generator mechanics in this example

Tags: python, generator

Can someone explain the mechanics of why it prints only 3 lines, instead of 24.  I know its due to the fact that the generator function is exhausted, but how?

```
def counter_gen(size):
    cur=1
    while cur <= size:
        yield cur
        cur +=1

c1=counter_gen(8)
c2=counter_gen(3)

for x in c1:
    for y in c2:
        print x,y
```

Comment: if you want a detailed explanation of generators in general, this very topic is the top rated python question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c2` reaches its end after 3 iterations. Iterating on it again will do nothing. That's what's meant by "exhausting" the iterator. So, after three items, it stops. Your outer iterator goes 8 times, but because the inner iterator only goes 3 times, only the first outer iteration does anything. The next 7 try to iterate over the exhausted iterator, and nothing happens.

If you want a *new* iteration of `c2` to start with each iteration of `c1`, simply write it that way!

```
c1=counter_gen(8)

for x in c1:
    c2=counter_gen(3)
    for y in c2:
        print x, y
```

Or, do away with the `c1` and `c2` entirely:

```
for x in counter_gen(8):
    for y in counter_gen(3):
        print x, y
```

Comment: Oh, how I've completely missed that,and started rationalizing that it must somehow sharing state in a way that was not making sense to me. Thank you, this cleared it up.

Answer (score 1):

`c1` and `c2` are generator objects. You can iterate over them once, then further calls to `next()` will raise `StopIteration`. Playing around in an interpreter should give you an idea of what's happening:

```
>>> c1 = counter_gen(3)
>>> for item in c1:
        pass
>>> c1.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> [i for i in c1]  # Exhausted, will immediately raise StopIteration
[]
```

Try creating a new generator in the body of the loop instead:

```
for x in counter_gen(8):
    for y in counter_gen(3):
        print x,y
```